# Microsoft Visual C++ - Compile one single DLL without dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I was given a huge Microsoft Visual C++ 2003 project that generates an executable (.exe) where the project itself is depending on several DLLs. I noticed that even if the code managed to compile, when it runs it will look for the DLLs that it depends on (say my program is called abc and the DLLs it depends on is called def.dll), and even if I add the path to include in the project settings, it will complain saying the DLL could not be found unless I add the folders containing def.dll to the %PATH% variable.

As such, the final product is not one exe but one exe with tonnes of DLL.

Is it possible to have everything compiled to one single .exe file so that I can just take this executable with me and it would run on every single PC that I have? The project itself is massive so I don't plan to change every single .h and .cpp file, but if there is a quick settings change in the visual C++ I think it would be nice. I know potentially the .exe would be 10 times as large and compiling it would probably take hours, but I think portability is rather important here.

Thanks!

PS: NOT sure why people are voting down this post...can I no longer ask legitimate questions on StackOverflow? I know the problem may sounds trivial to some of you guys, but I was really just simplifying the problem for the sake of illustration.

Comment: Put all the DLLs in the same directory as the executable and the job's done.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan except the DLLs are in different folders belonging to different dependency programs, I was simplifying this problem for the sake of illustration

Comment: Still, put copies in the executable directory is the accepted solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to rebuild the DLL into a standalone (static library) and add the static library to the linker settings.  However I do not recommend doing this if you do not know the preprocessor settings and possible code changes to create such a static library.

You can't just take the DLL source code and recompile it for a static library unless the authors give you the steps required in doing this task (usually you will need to define preprocessor constants using the -D option).  What those constants are and what additional steps to take -- the authors of the DLL must tell you this.

If the original authors of the DLL have never built a static library then again, I don't recommend you try it, unless you're a good to expert programmer that is familiar with what must be changed.  The authors in this case never intended the code to be used as a static library, therefore the changes to be made could be extensive.